# Gauge invariance and non-commuting second derivatives

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematics, gauge-symmetry

I'm currently doing a homework assignment in relativistic quantum mechanics, and one of the problems involves proving the gauge invariance of a particular lagrangian.

The problem is really quite simple, so long as you assume that the electromagnetic field tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$. However, I'd prefer to prove this, rather than assume it.

The standard proof found in many textbooks is very simple, but I have some trouble accepting it, as it seems to assume things that are not stated.

$$
F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - \partial^{\nu}A^{\mu} = \frac{\partial A^{\nu}}{\partial x_{\mu}} - \frac{\partial A^{\mu}}{\partial x_{\nu}}
$$

where A is the electromagnetic 4-potential. We define a gauge transformation by

$$
A^\mu \mapsto A^{\prime\mu} = A^{\mu} + \partial^\mu \lambda(\textbf{x}) = A^{\mu} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}}\lambda(\textbf{x})
$$

where $\lambda(\textbf{x})$ is an **arbitrary** scalar field.

By simple insertion, this gives us

$$
F^{\mu\nu} \mapsto F^{\prime\mu\nu} = \partial^\mu A^{\prime\nu} - \partial^\nu A^{\prime\mu} =
$$
$$
= \partial^\mu A^\nu + \partial^\mu \partial^\nu \lambda(\textbf{x}) - \partial^\nu A^\mu - \partial^\nu \partial^\mu \lambda(\textbf{x}) =
$$
$$
= F^{\mu\nu} + (\partial^\nu\partial^\mu - \partial^\mu\partial^\nu)\lambda(\textbf{x})
$$

Here's where the textbooks I've seen simply assume that the last term vanishes. I presume this is because they assume that the partial derivatives commute ...

... but this is not necessarily true if $\lambda(\textbf{x})$ is an **arbitrary** scalar field, is it? It would seem to assume that $\lambda(x)$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$, in order to conform with [Schwarz'/Clairaut's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Requirement_of_continuity).

I feel like I'm missing something here, and would greatly appreciate it if somebody could tell me *what* that is.

Are we to infer that the scalar fields used for gauge transformations are $\mathcal{C}^2$? Or does $(\partial^\nu\partial^\mu - \partial^\mu\partial^\nu)\lambda(\textbf{x})$ vanish regardless?

Comment: Yes, gauge transformations are, by assumption, smooth functions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you :) 
I figured something like that must be the case, but my textbooks in both EM field theory and quantum field theory keep insisting that the scalar field is **arbitrary** ... but then again, they clearly assume that it's differentiable, so I guess it's not too naughty to assume it's also C2.

Thanks again!